# kubernetes not creating the ELB for ingress-nginx controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to set up ingress-nginx-controller with type as *LoadBalancer*
using [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#elastic-load-balancer-elb) guide for the configuration.
Couple of issues I'm observing -
issue#1) It does not create and deploy a ELB onto the AWS.
issue#2) The *External-IP* status is showing as pending for ever.

```
$ kubectl get services -n ingress-nginx  
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE   
ingress-nginx   LoadBalancer   10.108.245.210   <pending>     80:30742/TCP,443:31028/TCP   41m
```

I've followed each step mentioned there

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/mandatory.yaml  
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/aws/service-l4.yaml  
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/aws/patch-configmap-l4.yaml
```

here is the logs from the pod -

```
~$ kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default-http-backend-7b8bdbc579-5tgd5       1/1     Running   0          5h57m
nginx-ingress-controller-766c77b7d4-w6wkk   1/1     Running   1          6h16m

$ kubectl logs -n ingress-nginx nginx-ingress-controller-766c77b7d4-w6wkk | more  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:    0.21.0
  Build:      git-b65b85cd9
  Repository: https://github.com/aledbf/ingress-nginx
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

nginx version: nginx/1.15.6
W1228 06:50:15.592738       7 client_config.go:548] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I1228 06:50:15.593115       7 main.go:196] Creating API client for https://10.96.0.1:443
I1228 06:50:15.699540       7 main.go:240] Running in Kubernetes cluster version v1.13 (v1.13.1) - git (clean) commit eec55b9ba98609a46fee712359c7b5b365bdd920 - platfo$
m linux/amd64
I1228 06:50:16.060958       7 nginx.go:258] Starting NGINX Ingress controller
I1228 06:50:16.098387       7 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"nginx-configuration", UID:"60a8d471-0a6c-11e9-9$
55-024a9b465fb2", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"1425", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/nginx-configuration
I1228 06:50:16.098548       7 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"tcp-services", UID:"60acc5c1-0a6c-11e9-9a55-024$
9b465fb2", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"1426", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/tcp-services
I1228 06:50:16.103229       7 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"udp-services", UID:"60ae5849-0a6c-11e9-9a55-024$
9b465fb2", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"1428", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/udp-services
I1228 06:50:17.262403       7 nginx.go:279] Starting NGINX process
I1228 06:50:17.263106       7 leaderelection.go:187] attempting to acquire leader lease  ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader-nginx...
I1228 06:50:17.267252       7 controller.go:172] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.
I1228 06:50:17.280698       7 leaderelection.go:196] successfully acquired lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader-nginx
I1228 06:50:17.281401       7 status.go:148] new leader elected: nginx-ingress-controller-766c77b7d4-w6wkk
I1228 06:50:18.113969       7 controller.go:190] Backend successfully reloaded.
I1228 06:50:18.114768       7 controller.go:202] Initial sync, sleeping for 1 second.
[28/Dec/2018:06:50:19 +0000]TCP200000.000
I1228 06:51:07.572896       7 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"nginx-configuration", UID:"60a8d471-
0a6c-11e9-9a55-024a9b465fb2", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"1783", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/nginx-configu
ration
I1228 06:51:07.995982       7 controller.go:172] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.
I1228 06:51:12.846822       7 controller.go:190] Backend successfully reloaded.
[28/Dec/2018:06:51:13 +0000]TCP200000.000
W1228 10:14:17.301340       7 queue.go:130] requeuing &ObjectMeta{Name:sync status,GenerateName:,Namespace:,SelfLink:,UID:,ResourceVersion:,Generation:0,Cre
ationTimestamp:0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC,DeletionTimestamp:<nil>,DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:nil,Labels:map[string]string{},Annotations:map[string]string
{},OwnerReferences:[],Finalizers:[],ClusterName:,Initializers:nil,}, err services "ingress-nginx" not found
W1228 10:14:17.313074       7 queue.go:130] requeuing &ObjectMeta{Name:sync status,GenerateName:,Namespace:,SelfLink:,UID:,ResourceVersion:,Generation:0,Cre
ationTimestamp:0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC,DeletionTimestamp:<nil>,DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:nil,Labels:map[string]string{},Annotations:map[string]string
{},OwnerReferences:[],Finalizers:[],ClusterName:,Initializers:nil,}, err services "ingress-nginx" not found
W1228 10:14:17.320110       7 queue.go:130] requeuing &ObjectMeta{Name:sync status,GenerateName:,Namespace:,SelfLink:,UID:,ResourceVersion:,Generation:0,Cre
ationTimestamp:0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC,DeletionTimestamp:<nil>,DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:nil,Labels:map[string]string{},Annotations:map[string]string
{},OwnerReferences:[],Finalizers:[],ClusterName:,Initializers:nil,}, err services "ingress-nginx" not found
<truncated>
```

The above error shows that service is not running properly. No event also showing up in describe service output-

```
~$ kubectl get service -n ingress-nginx
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default-http-backend   ClusterIP      10.100.2.163    <none>        80/TCP                       5h49m
ingress-nginx          LoadBalancer   10.108.221.18   <pending>     80:32010/TCP,443:31271/TCP   170m

$kubectl describe service ingress-nginx -n ingress-nginx
Name:                     ingress-nginx
Namespace:                ingress-nginx
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/part-of=ingress-nginx
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{"service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type":"nlb"},"label
s":{"app.k...
                          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/part-of=ingress-nginx
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.108.221.18
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  32010/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.4:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               https/TCP
NodePort:                 https  31271/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.4:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Local
HealthCheck NodePort:     30401
Events:                   <none>
```

I know there is a service specification tag *externalIPs* but expectation here is that once ELB instance is created, it will be auto populated  -

```
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalIPs:
  - {{ ingress_lb_address or vip or masterIP }}
```

Please let me know if anything I'm missing here.

Comment: In general, it takes a while for the load balancer to spin up. It is probably an issue if it takes longer than 10 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the root casue. *cloud provider* tag is missing from all resources in the cluster.

```
~$ kubectl cluster-info dump | grep LoadBalancer  
 E1228 14:35:47.072444 1 core.go:76] Failed to start service controller: WARNING: no cloud provider provided, services of type LoadBalancer will fail
```

Comment: how to set `cloud provider`, while installing kubeadm?

Comment: Add `KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--cloud-provider=aws` to `/etc/default/kubelet`

Answer (score 1):

aws ALB,CLB,ELB all take some what of time to configure in 5-10 min maximum time.

even you check out the link :https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/kubernetes-ingress-aws-alb-ingress-controller/

here is ingress controller with ALB

Comment: it's over 6 hours...nothing created. Do you have code where you got the ELB created and I can refer to it?

Comment: did you check for pod running ? actually i am using aws farget only let me check...!

Comment: AWS resource : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/kubernetes-ingress-aws-alb-ingress-controller/                         my git : https://github.com/harsh4870/ingress-aws

Comment: I've added the log. pz check it. The pods log showing as *err services "ingress-nginx" not found*. it might be  because service is not proper

Comment: yes may be cause of service of only or may deployment type.

Comment: you know aws fargate easy way to handle ELB and ALB and CLB there. if small application you can direct deploy container there only